# SailsJS populate with select records

Tags: select, sails.js, record, populate

OperationalError [UsageError]: Invalid populate(s).
Details:
Could not populate `parentId`.  This is a singular ("model") association, which means it never refers to more than *one* associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, since it generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's the trouble-- it looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) *was* provided!
(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special case that *does* make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version of Waterline.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to:-

```
 node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/forge-stage-two-query.js
```

Go to this section :-

```
if(populateAttrDef.model) {
```

Change it to:-

```
if (populateAttrDef.model) {

    // Tolerate a subcriteria of `{}`, interpreting it to mean that there is
    // really no criteria at all, and that we should just use `true` (the
    // default "enabled" value for singular "model" associations.)
    if (_.isEqual(query.populates[populateAttrName], {})) {
      query.populates[populateAttrName] = true;
    }
    // Otherwise, this simply must be `true`.  Otherwise it's invalid.
    else {

      if (query.populates[populateAttrName] !== true && (_.isUndefined(query.populates[populateAttrName].select) && _.isUndefined(query.populates[populateAttrName].omit))) {
        throw buildUsageError(
          'E_INVALID_POPULATES',
          'Could not populate `' + populateAttrName + '`.  ' +
          'This is a singular ("model") association, which means it never refers to ' +
          'more than _one_ associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as ' +
          'the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, ' +
          'since it generally wouldn\'t make any sense.  But that\'s the trouble-- it ' +
          'looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) _was_ provided!\n' +
          '(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special ' +
          'case that _does_ make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version ' +
          'of Waterline.)\n' +
          '\n' +
          'Here\'s what was passed in:\n' +
          util.inspect(query.populates[populateAttrName], { depth: 5 }),
          query.using
        );
      } else {
        query.populates[populateAttrName] = {
          select: query.populates[populateAttrName].select ? query.populates[populateAttrName].select : undefined,
          omit: query.populates[populateAttrName].omit ? query.populates[populateAttrName].omit : undefined
        };
      }

    }//>-•

  }
```